# Where do we use the maximum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction, free-body-diagram

[image]

In the above problem,we have been asked to find the **maximum** value of $\frac{M}{m}$. But the solution the book ended up giving is the normal balancing of forces in free body diagram and came up with the answer $\frac{M}{m}=\frac{\mu}{\sin \theta-\mu\cos \theta}$, I don't see the point of mentioning the word *maximum* for the ratio if we get the same answer every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important concept you may be missing is that the static friction force is a variable. It matches the force that opposes it up until the maximum possible static friction is reached, which is $\mu N$ where $N$ is the force normal (perpendicular) to the surface.

Consequently, reason the word "maximum" is used is because the blocks can be at rest for all $M/m$ less than that which results in *both* the  maximum possible static friction force between $M$ and the surface and between $m$ and the surface from being exceeded, at which point sliding occurs. In short, the blocks will be at rest for all $M/m$ less than that which causes both blocks to slide.

That should be evident to you if you were given the complete solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is the maximum value of $M/m$ because the derivation assumed that the maximum static frictional force was exactly enough to stop block $M$ from sliding down the ramp. If $M$ were increased in mass, the block would slide down because the frictional force would no longer be sufficient to prevent the sliding. If the mass $M$ was reduced, there would still be no motion because the static frictional force would be smaller.