# Static friction acting on both bodies in half-atwood machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

Consider the following figure. Let's say we want to find the static friction force acting on each mass for the system to remain at rest.

[image]

$$T - F_1 = 0$$
$$m_2 g - T - F_2 = 0$$

So these are $2$ equations for $3$ unknowns. Even though the total static friction force $F_1+ F_2$ acting on the whole system of $2$ masses may be determined, it feels weird that this can not be solved for $F_1$ and $F_2$ separately. Obviously it is not the maximum values $\mu_1 N_1$ and $\mu_2 N_2$ what I want, but the actual values.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my equation for $m_2$, since the existence of friction $F_2$ should imply the existence of a horizontal normal force $N_2$ which would accelerate $m_2$ to the right, making it impossible for the system to remain at rest. Therefore, $N_2 = 0$ and $F_2=0$ and then there are only $2$ unknowns $T$ and $F_1$.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: for the reasons that you said, you can assume there is no $F_2$

Comment: What would be the source of a force normal to the surface against m2?

Comment: @Bob D electromagnetism between atoms and molecules I guess, the same as $m_1$  (I am not claiming $N_2$ exists though, I am just saying what would be its source if it existed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for static friction to exist between $m_2$ and the surface of the block, there needs to be a force acting perpendicular to the surface of the block (a normal force).

Assuming the surface of the block next to $m_2$ is exactly at an angle of 90 deg with the horizontal, then the only forces acting on $m_2$ are the vertical forces of gravity acting downward ($mg$) and the tension in the string ($T$) acting upward. Under those conditions, theoretically there is no static friction force acting on $m_2$.

On the other hand, in reality is there any such thing as an exactly vertical wall (*exactly* 90 deg with horizontal)?

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps indeed. What about a more real wall, so that $m_2$ in at rest over an inclined plane with angle $\beta $? Now $m_2 g \sin \beta - T - F_2 = 0$ and again there's $3$ unknowns. Or is it $T=0$ when the system is at rest?

Comment: Now it becomes a whole different (and interesting) question.  See my answer to the following: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667133/static-friction-acting-on-both-bodies-in-half-atwood-machine/667143#667143 If that doesn't help, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: that link is not sending me to a different answer

Comment: @Javi Sorry. Meant this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666732/where-do-we-use-the-maximum/666744#666744